# How to replace black background with white on image resizing using Thumbnailator?

Tags: java, png, jpeg

I use Thumbnailator to convert images from png to jpg and then resize them:

```
Thumbnails.of(new File("C:/279.png"))
                .outputFormat("JPG")
                .size(100, 100)
                .outputQuality(1.0)
                .toFile(new File("C:/279.jpg"));
```

Original image has transparent background, but output image has black background. How to set white background on output image?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

Use `.addFilter(new Canvas(100, 100, Positions.CENTER, Color.WHITE))`

Example:

```
Thumbnails.of(new File("C:/279.png"))
            .outputFormat("JPG")
            .size(100, 100)
            .addFilter(new Canvas(100, 100, Positions.CENTER, Color.WHITE))
            .outputQuality(1.0)
            .toFile(new File("C:/279.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Somebody from https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator/issues/41 had a solution that worked for me. Simply adding `.imageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)`

So

```
Thumbnails.of(new File("C:/279.png"))
            .outputFormat("JPG")
            .size(100, 100)
            .imageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)
            .outputQuality(1.0)
            .toFile(new File("C:/279.jpg"));
```